# Proving an extension of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Fatou's Lemma states:

> Let $(f_n) : \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Then 
>   $$\int \lim \inf f_n \le \lim \inf \int f_n.$$

Later, my professor wrote

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions which is bounded below by an integrable function $g$. Then 
>   $$\int \lim \inf f_n \le \lim \inf \int f_n.$$

I am having two issues with this extension.

$1)$ Don't we need to assume that the $f_n$'s are eventually integrable? My reason for thinking this is that the straightforward method of proof that I do below seems to require it.

$2)$ What codomain can the $f_n$'s have? My proof below uses the linearity of the integral, but I only know that the integral is linear for functions with codomain $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible for both $f_n$ and $g$ to have codomain $[-\infty, \infty]$?

Thank you very much for your help.

**My Work:**

Assuming that the $f_n$'s are eventually integrable, and we have codomain $\mathbb{R}$, we have $f_n \ge g \implies f_n-g \ge 0$. Applying Fatou's Lemma to $f_n - g$, we get

$$\int \lim \inf (f_n-g) \le \lim \inf \int (f_n-g).$$

We know $g$ is integrable, we can write

$$\int \lim \inf (f_n) - \int g \le \lim \inf \int (f_n) - \int g$$

and deduce the desired result.

Comment: Why can we write $\int \liminf (f_n -g)=\int \liminf f_n -\int g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No further assumptions are necessary. Integrability of $g$ implies that it takes values in $\mathbb R$ except on a set of measure $0$. $f_n$'s may take infinite values for this proof to work.

Comment: But on the RHS, we used $\int (f_n-g) = \int f_n - \int g$. Don't we need to know that both functions are integrable in order to do this?

Comment: $\int (f_n-g)$ surely exists but it may be $+\infty$. Since $g$ is integrable this implies that $\int f_n$ also exists ( in the sense either $\int f_n^{+}$ or $\int f_n^{-}$ is finite); of course $\int f_n $ may be $\infty$ but the integral exists an an extended real number.  @Ovi

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in general, $\int(f \pm g)$ may not equal $\int f \pm \int g$. But if $g$ is integrable (and no restrictions on $f$), then always $\int (f \pm g) = \int f \pm \int g$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @Ovi

Comment: Thank you ${}{}$